# How to determine a tweet contains a video link with the twitter api?

Tags: twitter

I am using the twitter api to pull back a users tweets. I then want to loop through the tweets and if a tweet contains a video (ex. a link to a youtube vid) I want to display the video in my page. The issue is it doesn't seem like there is anything in the JSON returned by the twitter API when calling the user_timelime REST function to determine that a tweet contains a link to a video. I know I could scan the url passed back for the word "youtube" but I want this to scale across any site the user plugs a link into that contains a video.

I may be missing something in the JSON twitter is giving back but I am not to sure.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

See this link https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/entities-in-twitter-objects#extended_entities

Twitter API provides all URLs to the media files included in the tweet

Comment: According to the documentation, this only assists in locating pictures, not videos.

Comment: `tweet.entities.urls[i]` contains references, including video 

[Twitter API with Example](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/platform-objects/entities)

`"urls":[{"indices":[32,52], "url":"http:\/\/t.co\/IOwBrTZR", "display_url":"youtube.com\/watch?v=oHg5SJ\u2026", "expanded_url":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0"}]`

``

Comment: All URLs to media files, or all URLs?